# Windows 10 WDM Audio Issue

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-services

I'm running Windows 10 1903, the problem appeared after installing update [KB4507453](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4507453/windows-10-update-kb4507453)

- The **Windows Audio service** wouldn't start, I solved the problem by changing the "log on as:" from **user** to **local system account**. Windows reports no error anymore but no sound coming out of my speakers (SPDIF)
- The problem is **not driver related**, I reinstalled the drivers, downgraded to an older version and upgraded to the newest WHQL drivers, Windows reported no errors.
- I tested my audio with Adobe Audition where audio is played by the [**ASIO**] library instead of the Windows [MME] system, the **audio works perfect**!
- I installed the **ASIO4all plugin** in **Winamp** and also here **audio plays** perfectly.
- So the problem lies on the **Windows MME or WASAPI system** (don't know what is actually used by Windows programs), in Audition the MME system reports: "The default output device is not responding and may be disconnected..."
- In the Windows Sound configuration applet the in- and output devices appear as usual but **no sound is detected** in the **microphone** or no sound is outputted in the **playback** device when I play audio trough a DirectSound output (a normal Windows program).
- When I try to play a **test tone** in the Advanced tab of the Windows Sound configuration applet I get an error dialog that says: "Failed to play test tone".
- I tried **uninstalling the update** that caused the problem but without result. Reinstalling it also gave no result.
- My previous **Windows Image** is from one month ago so I would prefer to solve the problem instead of reverting to the one month old image.

Are there any things I can do to investigate or solve my problem. Reinstalling Windows is no option for me as my Windows is highly customised in many many years.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately after a month of trial and error the only solution was a **fresh install of Windows 10**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, which I was able to fix with these steps:

1. Go to Windows 10's sound settings. On the right side, click "Sound Control Panel".
2. Double click the device with the issue.
3. Go to the "Advanced" tab, click the dropdown in the "Default Format" section, and select another format. Then revert back to the previous one (it may be necessary to do it a pair of times).

After changing and reverting the format (no need to click "Apply", restarting, or anything else), the sound was working again.

Later I discovered that the issue had been caused by some program (Vegas Pro 15) changing the sound card sample rate. I have no idea why that causes the sound to not work even after restarting, but I can reproduce the issue every time I change the sample rate (ASIO works fine, though), as well as the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same symptoms. Windows 10, 22H2, Realtek HD Audio, ESI Maya 44 USB and AMD HDMI Audio. None of it works from Windows audio, but the ESI device works with ASIO.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1184524)